# Have dual citizenship with expiring US passport

Tags: usa, passports, dual-nationality

My daughter has dual citizenship, US and Taiwan. We are traveling in October to Germany for a 2 week visit. Her US passport expires in December. I know entering Germany you have to have at least 3 months remaining on your passport.

Can we check in with the airline using her Taiwanese passport? We plan to enter and exit Germany using that passport.

I am just worried that the airline will ask for the US passport and since it is expiring refuse to let her on the flight. We are flying with Turkish Airline.
It is taking longer than ever to get US passports renewed now.

Comment: If you're using the Taiwanese passport to enter Germany, why would the airline care about the US passport on the way there? On the way back you'll have no problem

Comment: Are you going to the US?

Comment: Does your daughter's Taiwanese passport contain an identity card number?  If not, she cannot use it for visa-free travel to the Schengen area: https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02018R1806-20230515#E0015

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple passports, you have in most cases free choice which one to use for travel. That's clearly the case here (unless you are planning to enter the US). If your daughter has a valid Taiwanese passport with an ID number, she can use this for entry into Schengen without problems.

> I am just worried that the airline will ask for the US passport

It's none of their business which passport you are using. They will only deal with the one you present at check in. If that's good, you are ready to go.

> Can we check in with the airline using her Taiwanese passport?

Yes. Starting in 2024 she may need a ETIAS but until then a regular passport should be fine. To make sure put your (or your daughter's) exact details into here: https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm

Even if you are planning to go the US, you can enter and leave Germany with the Taiwanese passport and check-in to your US flight with your US passport. You can switch passports between countries on the same itinerary.